# Highcharts, how to change hover bg color for series with multiple columns (categories)

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

In highcharts, there is a background color for all the columns in a series. In all the themes, the hover color is a light blue (155, 200, 255, .2).

I have an example loaded here: http://jsfiddle.net/38pvL4cb/

You can see in the source that Highcharts is creating a path as follows:

```
<path fill="none" d="M 678.5 49 L 678.5 326" stroke="rgba(155,200,255,0.2)" stroke-width="274.25" zIndex="2" visibility="hidden"></path>
```

This element dynamically moves and is shown based on where you hover. I am trying to figure out in the theme how to change it's color, but can't find it in the [API reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.categories).

Answer (score 3):

Set `xAxis.crosshair.color` option: http://jsfiddle.net/38pvL4cb/5/

```
xAxis: {
    gridLineColor: '#707073',
    labels: {
        style: {
            color: '#fff'
        }
    },
    crosshair: {
        color: "red" // color
    },
    lineColor: '#707073',
    minorGridLineColor: '#505053',
    tickColor: '#707073',
    title: {
        style: {
            color: '#777'

        }
    }
},
```

That option is not yet in the API.

Comment: Thanks! I was struggling to find which option controlled this - it seems like it would be called "backgroundColor" for category series since it highlights the background.

Comment: Glad to hear it helps! Crosshair always used `color` for this. I think it's a good idea to not introduce another option just because size of the crosshair changed? See: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/31toj2aL/ - set fixed width to 2px and with another option it would be confusing which one to use. Plus there is only 6 options for a crosshair, check [API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.crosshair).

Answer (score 0):

Add some CSS targeting the stroke-color like this:

```
.highcharts-container path
{
    stroke: rgba(100,100,100,.5);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/38pvL4cb/1/)

Comment: The problem is Highcharts uses path's for more than just this element, so doing a general address to path causes problems with other charts. I added a second chart to the jsfiddle below that demonstrates the problems with just address all paths. This unique hover path does not have an id, and therefore can not be called directly.

Comment: Than you might have to edit the highcharts.js file.. Look for: (e?"rgba(155,200,255,0.2)":"#C0C0C0")